# Elastic server is not able to communication with latest version 8.4.3 or 8.4.1

Tags: elasticsearch

Started docker container elastic with version 8.4.1.
I can see it on the docker-desktop  running but when I open it from the browser .
Getting error
This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

using curl also i'm getting error
curl: (52) Empty reply from server.